# JavaConverters is not working as expected as JavaConversions

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I've below code snippet. it is working fine with warning in scala 2.11

```
    import java.util.{ ArrayList => JAList }

    val jlist = new JAList[String]()
    jlist.add("123")
    jlist.add("234")

    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

    jlist.mkString("")
```

warning message is `object JavaConversions in package collection is deprecated use JavaConverters instead`.

I've updated the JavaConversions to JavaConverters.(i.e., updated import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ to import scala.collection.JavaConverters._)

I now get the error `mkString is not a member of java.util.List[String]`.

What is that I need to change in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implicit type conversions are generally discouraged. With `JavaConverters` we're encouraged to be more explicit as to exactly where/when the conversions take place.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

jlist.asScala.mkString  //res0: String = 123234
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

jList.asScala.mkString
```

this should work.